# How can I edit my "About me" section after editing it once?

Tags: support, profile-page

I filled my "About me" section about two months ago. Now I want to make some changes to it. I cannot find any option to change it. How can I do this?

Note I mostly run Stack Overflow from mobile and sometimes from a computer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/12269857 or https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current. You can also go to your profile and click "Edit profile and settings". It's above your gravatar, if you're in the profile tab or above your rep graph if you are in the Activity tab.

Comment: And one more question double-beep when I visited your profile how your about me know that the visitor was me?

Comment: @WasifHasan Read the url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are mainly two ways to do that.

The first way is to go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) URL to edit it directly. This will redirect you to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/12269857`, where, as you can see, `current` is replaced with your user id. That's also why `https://stackoverflow.com/users/current` redirects to viewer's profile - because `current` becomes their user id.

The second way is to go to your profile (click gravatar):

[image]

click "Edit profile and settings"

[image]

and scroll to the About me section:

> [image]

Finally, when you're done, scroll down to the bottom and save your changes:

[image]